# Subquery returning more than 1 value when trying to display images

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to create a Photo Gallery page.
This page will display a number of groups (Tennis, Golf, etc.). Each group can have a number of Photo Collection's and each Collection can have a number of images.

I am using nested repeaters, to first display Group names, then Photo Collection Names and then the images.

If I have one image in a collection, my code works fine. But when I add a second image to the collection, I get the below error in my C# which I have posted below :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

The purpose of this query is to retrieve all images connected to that photo collection.

What changes do I need to make in order to display all images for each collection, rather than just one?

```
 <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title"><%# Eval("Group_Name") %></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="repPhotoAlbums" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repPhotoAlbums_ItemDataBound">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <h5><%# Eval("Name") %></h5>
                                            <asp:Repeater ID="repPhotos" runat="server">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("filename","../Images/{0}") %>' title='<%#Eval("imageDesc") %>' rel="lightbox[Brussels]">
                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("filename", "../Images/{0}") %>' runat="server" Width="112" Height="84" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--col-lg-12-->
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                            <!--panel-body-->
```

C#:

```
   protected void repPhotoAlbums_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repPhotos = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repPhotos"));


        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "p_Collection_Id").ToString();
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id, filename, imageDesc FROM Group_Images WHERE ID = (Select g_Image_Id = Group_Image_Id FROM Photo_Collection_Images WHERE Photo_Collection_Id = '" + Group_Id + "');", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repPhotos.DataSource = dt;
        repPhotos.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Also, I can post the SQL tables which store this data if that helps.
Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `exists()`:

```
select 
   Id
 , filename
 , imageDesc
from Group_Images as g
where exists (
  select 1 
  from Photo_Collection_Images as i
  where g.Id = i.Group_Image_Id
    and i.Photo_Collection_Id = '" + Group_Id + "'
  )
```

> Note: For actual use, this sort of code needs to use parameters to prevent [sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: This should be parameterized.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, but I'm guessing this is coursework and they haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: That could be. I am just saying that is needs to be mentioned because anything else would be remiss. There may be others stumble in here looking for an answer and splatter this on their website.

Comment: I think the choice of "splatter" was particularly moving. Very nice! note added.

Comment: @SqlZim Hi, I'm having a similar problem with this code: `@"DECLARE @Group_Id INT; 
                            DECLARE @Another_Id INT;

                            SELECT @Group_Id = Id
                            FROM dbo.Photo_Collection
                            WHERE Id @Id

                            SELECT @Another_Id = Group_Image_Id
                            FROM Photo_Collection_Images
                            WHERE Photo_Collection_Id = @Group_Id

                            SELECT * FROM Group_Images
                            WHERE ID = @Another_Id;"`

Comment: The above is only returning one image also, when there are 2 associated. I've tried inserting an _in_ here but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @user2911539 Post your table schemas and example data like this: [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`. Also, use parameterised statements instead of string concatenations:

```
select Id,
    filename,
    imageDesc
from Group_Images
where ID in (
        select Group_Image_Id
        from Photo_Collection_Images
        where Photo_Collection_Id = @Group_id
        )
```

Or use Join:

```
select i.Id,
    i.filename,
    i.imageDesc
from Group_Images i
join Photo_Collection_Images c on i.ID = c.Group_Image_Id
where c.Photo_Collection_Id = @Group_id
```